# Invite via Facebook is not working in Signed apk

Tags: android, facebook, invite, facebook-invite

I got Facebook invite working in unsigned apk. But when I signed the apk it showing a Dialog saying  "App would like to access your public profile and friend list" and when I press OK nothing happens. What should I do? Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you properly created HashKeys for your developer account?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the keyhash with the newly generated keyhash, which you need to save in the settings page of the facebook developer site, where you had registered the app.

Try the following bash command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

to generate the keyhash, don't forget to replace  with your alias name that you gave while signing the apk. and the path where your keystore lies instead of **~/.android/debug.keystore**.

Then, register this on the facebook developer site in the keyhash text box:

[image]

Now everything will be fine.

Comment: I added KeyHash but the result is same

Comment: what does your logcat say? check for the facebook exceptions. If it's case of keyhash error it will tell you saying "Keyhash Mismatch"

Comment: Also make sure that you have coded the onActivity method. to catch the call back event

Answer (score 0):

Is your onActivityResult calls after facebook dialog dissmiss if no then override this method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     mSessionManager.onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

or if you already did this then add brekpoint here and check data